# UITableView - Execute a different function in primary view controller, based on row number of UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

Using the following code to create my UITableView which works well:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(arrayOfImages.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewController2TableViewCell

    cell.niceImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImages[indexPath.row] + ".png")

    return(cell)

}
```

Then, I am using the following code to unwind segue onto ViewController1 and execute my function, which also works well:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destVC = segue.destination as! ViewController

    destVC.posn += 1

    destVC.myFunction(Parameter1: 1)
```

arrayOfImages contains 10 images (for now). I want each image (aka each row in my UITableView) to execute a different function in destVC. I.e the function is dependant on row number. Using the above code, the same function is executed on every row, which is not ideal

I tried utilising the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex = indexPath.row
}
```

And then making my function dependant on indexPath.row's value, but myIndex always came up as 0, regardless of what row it actually was

Answer (score 0):

You send integer 1 for your destVC function's parameter everytime. Thats the problem. Send the selected indexPath.row of tableView in `prepareForSegue` method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let destVC = segue.destination as! ViewController
        destVC.posn += 1
        destVC.myFunction(Parameter1: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```